# What is the best machine learning approach for data error correction?

Tags: machine-learning

I have the following problem: I have a set of raw data entered manually. These data are evaluated by business rules and eventually generate integrity errors, mostly.

Then these errors are manually handled and the correction is performed manually.

What is the best approach in machine learning to implement an algorithm that look at this historical corrections and suggest the correct approach.

Note: all data are structured and business rules are evaluated mostly at foreign keys restrictions.

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! Please provide examples of the types of data, and errors you encounter, along with the corresponding corrections. Do you have any restrictions on the tools or approaches you are allowed to use?